# Android Bluetooth socket connection takes too long and eventually failed

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect a bluetooth device from the Android phone. In most cases, the connection is successful.
I am making the socket connection using the following code:

```
        if (isUsingHtcTypeConnectionScheme) {
            try { 
                if (LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG,"connecting to SPP with createRfcommSocket");
                Method m = mRemoteDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
                tmpSocket = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(mRemoteDevice, 1); // may be from 1 to 3
            } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException!!!", e);
            } catch ( java.lang.IllegalAccessException e ){
                Log.e(TAG, "java.lang.IllegalAccessException!!!", e);
            } catch ( java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException e ){
                Log.e(TAG, "java.lang.InvocationTargetException!!!", e);
            }
        }

        if (tmpSocket == null) {
            try {
                if (LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG,"connecting to SPP with createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord");
                tmpSocket = mRemoteDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid); // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the given BluetoothDevice
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "socket create failed", e);
            }
        }

        mBtSocket = tmpSocket;

        try {
            mBtSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            setState(STATE_IDLE);
            return;
        }
```

And if the other device's bluetooth is not on, it will throw the IOException in 2-3 seconds, this is the normal behavior.

But sometimes the connection takes 20-30 seconds and eventually failed, and the other device's bluetooth is on.

I am wondering why this happens, if the phone cannot connect to device, it should throw IOException in 2-3 seconds. But now is taking 20-30 seconds to throw the IOException. (And the other device is ready for connection actually)

I tested on several Android phones and also have this problem, so may not be related to specific phone.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: That is a good line of code you have got there.